# tns device run --device giving Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: android, nativescript, genymotion

I am trying to run Nativescript ann in Genymotion emulator.
but its trowing **Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined**

[image]

Comment: iTunes is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found an answer, but this fixed it for me:

1. Run `tns device` to get the list of devices connected to the machine.
2. Use the device identifier from the previous command and run the following:

```
tns device run --device <device identifier>
```

Comment: @Tvde1 strange that he is getting a device identifier that is a network address. How do you have your environment set up? Is the phone connected via USB? Or did he/you do something different than starting up an emulator? As mine show up as "emulator-****"

Answer (score 0):

Command format :

```
tns device run <Application ID> [--device <Device ID>]
```

You must include `Application ID` part:

```
tns device run org.nativescript.MyProject  --device myDevice
```

and first of all just simply run the project on your device like this:

```
tns run android  --device myDevice
```

then `tns device run` should be available without issues!